How can I prevent a dropdown from being concealed by another element?
Okay so, what I'm trying to achieve is this: I should be able to have a huge dropdown menu when I click the dropdown button.
Something like this:

This does work if I create a dropdown using bootstrap's popper and then stuff a bunch of br's under it so it doesn't float to the top. However, as soon as I try to add more items it clips as well.

Things I've tried so far:

Setting the overflow of the parent div to visible.
!important s (I know it's bad practice).
Changing the z-index.
Disabling the popper positioning, which leads to another issue where the dropdown button completely ignores the padding.



.stripcontainer {
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px grey solid;
  padding: 2% !important;
  overflow: visible !important;
}

.dropdown {
  overflow: visible !important;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  z-index: 1000 !important;
  overflow: visible !important;
}
<div id="filterstrip" className="stripcontainer">
  <div className="dropdown">
    <button className="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    
    <ul className="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
              Action
            </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
              Another action
            </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
              Something else here
            </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
              Something else here
            </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
              Something else here
            </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
              Something else here
            </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
              Something else here
            </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
              Something else here
            </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
              Something else here
            </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
              Something else here
            </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
              Something else here
            </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
              Something else here
            </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
              Something else here
            </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
              Something else here
            </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
              Something else here
            </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
              Something else here
            </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
              Something else here
            </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
              Something else here
            </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
              Something else here
            </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>




Please revise the demo above so it shows your problem. If you're using Bootstrap, first tag your version, then load it in the demo via CDN.

The demo is a snippet, not the entire page, it is a react component, not a HTML thing.

Well, you'll need to figure out a way to show us the problem. We can't debug it in our minds. See [ask].
